# Regex for detecting numbers away from each other?

Tags: regex, ip, port, range

so basically I want to detect if in these strings:

Hello 123 My 222 dear 112 troll 12 8889

192.1.1.254:10000

the numbers are in a format like this:
[0 to 255][ANYTHING][0 to 255][ANYTHING][0 to 255][ANYTHING][0 to 255][ANYTHING][0 to 65536]

Does anyone know how I can build such a regex?

It is for detecting if anyone posts an IP:Port in unusual format to bypass default ip:port filters.

Edit: As for the first comment: I do not know regex and what I have tried is:

```
if(regex_match("192.168 najlepszy serwer SAMP!!1 1 join1!! 8080","/^[0-2](*)?[0-5](*)?[0-5](*).(*)[0-2](*)?[0-5](*)?[0-5](*).(*)[0-2](*)?[0-5](*)?[0-5](*).(*)[0-2](*)?[0-5](*)?[0-5](*)?$/"))
{
    print("Cannot send message");
}
else
{
    print("New message for everyone! :)");
}
```

and some other not working regexes.

Comment: Port numbers are strictly less than 65536 (max 65535).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you read up on Regex syntax. For starters `.` is special and matches any character. Also doing something like `[0-2][0-5][0-5]` won't catch something like `192` as 9 is not within 0-5.

According to your requirements here's a Regex that should roughly do what you want

`([0-2]?\d{1,2}).*([0-2]?\d{1,2}).*([0-2]?\d{1,2}).*([0-2]?\d{1,2}).*(\d{1,5})?`

Each of the `([0-2]?\d{1,2})` portions will match 1 or 2 digits preceded optionally with a 0,1, or 2. Each `()` will capture a group which you can then examine using a Regex engine. You will need to examine this group as the Regex for each of those portions will match numbers above 255 (specifically 256-299).

The last group `(\d{1,5})?` is to catch the port number, again you will have to examine this as it will catch any 1 to 5 digit number (hence the `{1,5}`). The `?` makes the group optional, remove it if you want it to have to match against a port number.

As far as doing Regex in C, I haven't had much experience but there should be a way to get all the grouped matches and inspect them. Unfortunately they will be strings so you will have to convert them to integers to examine them.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to complicate your life checking the exact ranges, the simple regex would be:

```
/^.*(\d)+.+(\d)+.+(\d)+.+(\d)+.+(\d)+.*$/
```

The first four **(\d)+** parts can be replaced with more complicated check for 0-255 range:

```
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

the last **(\d)+** replace with next for port range check:

```
(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d\d|6[0-4]\d\d\d|[1-5]\d\d\d\d|[1-9]\d{0,3})
```

Comment: before I accept this I would like to point one thing out:
/^.*(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).+(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).+(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).+(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).+(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d\d|6[0-4]\d\d\d|[1-5]\d\d\d\d|[1-9]\d{0,3}).*$
/works great , just, it detects "127 0 0 1" also, but it needs to be at least "127 0 0 1 1" let's say..
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ <- just try it out hehe :D

Comment: I don't think you want .* for the separator.  I think you want \D or something which excludes \d, because otherwise the .* will consume all leading digits of the number (unless you use .*?) and even if you used .*? it would consume digits which caused the number to exceed the maximums you supply

Comment: I did not try many test cases and it depends on the regex engine you are using, but if you use the word boundary `\b` to separate the integer values, then `.*` should be fine as separator, yielding something like `\b<range-pattern>\b.*\b<range-pattern>\b`.

Answer (score 1):

An exact, simple, and direct representation of your pattern as a regular expression is not possible in the general case. The reason are the number ranges. Something like "at this place any integral number with a value from a to b" is just to complex. A regular expression is executed by a finite state machine and these (theoretical) beasts are (basically) only able to look at strings character by character. Therefore you can match something like "ignore all characters until you find the first digit, then check whether the first digit is followed by at most two more digits".

As a workaround you may try to build a list of alternations of possible digit patterns that covers your desired range of values (in the extreme case list every single value like `\b(?:1|2|3|4|...|154|155|...|255)\b`). I have a pattern for the range 0-255, but I have none for the range of possible port numbers. So a first approximation may be (really, this is only an approximation and not thoroughly tested):

```
\b(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b.*\b(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b.*\b(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b.*\b(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b[^0-9]*[0-9]{1,5}
```

In the above pattern `(?: .... )` means a shy group (not remembered for back references) and `\b` means word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need regex for this? In my opinion, you do not need regex for this.
Just split numbers into groups which are seperated by non-numeric characters. Then analyze.

What language?

As for actually looking for valid range, take a look at this;
http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: it's C. and how would I split "by non numeric" characters as fast as possible? (in a char string) | And how would I combine the regexes from that page?

Comment: man strtok - you'll need to enumerate all non-numeric characters, or write your own equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this simple regex

```
((\d|\D)+)*
```